# can't catch a parameter value in an Informatica mapping

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Parameter file is visible in a workflow. It's also set to be used in a session containing the mapping.

Either layout has the same variable $$src_file defined.

```
[Global]
$$src_file='file1'

[folder_FILESAPP.WF:wf_FILES.ST:s_FILES]
$$src_file='file2'
```

But when I'm trying to use it in a, let's say, source qualifier, this variable never gets caught.

```
select $$src_file from dual;
```

Apologies for a dumb question, going in circles here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the variable to be picked up, two things needs to be defined,

1. Define the variable in the mapping under Mappings tab -> parameter and variables.
2. go to workflow manger and under workflow , define the path of the parameter file. If using pmcmd command then pass the path of the parameter file next to "-param" attribute.

Comment: Tru dat, albeit making little sense. Why, if you define the parameter file, you can't see its parameters until you explicitly add those. But it did work, discovered this in parallel with the answer. And, thank you!

Comment: A parameter file can be passed dynamically. If you use pmcmd command you can pass a new file Everytime. Also a parameter file can also be common for many wf if a global variable is defined. That's why it needs explicit definition. This is all to ensure unwanted failures in the workflow when running from the backend